IC identification - Analog Devices IC with top marking “S IL"
Please help me to identify this IC. It is an Analog Devices chip in the MSOP-8 package.
The top marking "S IL".


It's an Analog Devices ADG1419BRMZ SPDT switch. The actual marking is S1L.


(Source: lcsc.com)
